# Redireccionar solo si hay token pero pasando el referer ultimo

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, nodejs

Estoy haciendo una redirección en el sitio 1 hacía el sitio 2 mediante este script incorporado en el head del sitio 1:

```
<script>
window.location.href = 'http://www.sitio2.com/?redirect=true';
</script>
```

y luego en el sitio 2 en el index.php incluyo esto en el head:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET["redirect"])) {
    $hash = $_GET["redirect"];
    if ($hash !== "") {
      header("Location: http://www.sitiofinal3.com");
      die();
    }
  }
?>
```

Bien, si el usuario entra al sitio 1 va directamente al sitio 2 y este último le redirigira a un tercer y final sitio. En cambio si accedo al sitio 2 sin pasar por el sitio 1 no hará ninguna redirección al sitio 3. Esto está claro y funciona bien. El problema es que cuándo el usuario llega al sitio 3, el sitio 3 ve como referer el sitio 1 y no el sitio 2.

Necesito que cuándo el usuario aterriza en la página final (en el ejemplo, es la página 3) el referer que se vea sea el sitio 2 y no el 1 como sucede ahora. Qué puedo hacer? me sería de gran ayuda.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y si en el sitio 2 de igual manera redireccionas con `JavaScript` en vez de `PHP`?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes redireccionar en el sitio 2 con `JavaScript` tal como tienes en el sitio 1.

El código sería algo así:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET["redirect"])) {
    $hash = $_GET["redirect"];
    if ($hash !== "") {

        echo "<script>
                window.location.href = 'http://www.sitiofinal3.com';
              </script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

De esta manera la redirección se hace desde el navegador y debería de tirarte en el sitio 3 el referer correcto.

Comment: Gracias @Jemonge funciona perfecto, lo que hay un problema ahora, el referer en el sitio 3 es el sitio 2 (esto es correcto ahora) pero me sale en este formato: http://sitio2.com/?redirect=true , ¿hay alguna forma de poder hacer que el referer sea el dominio .com a secas sin el valor del ?redirect=true? es decir, que el referer final llegado al sitio 3, sea sitio2.com a secas

Comment: @DavidMatas cómo estás obteniendo el referer?

Comment: Podrías eliminiar los parámetros de la URL así: `$url = explode("?", $referer);
echo $url[0];`

Comment: Hola @Jemonge, gracias por tu pronta respuesta. He añadido la línea de código que me has dicho en el sitio2.com (en el trozo de en medio del fragmento que me pasaste entre el hash y el echo script para hacer la redirección) pero me sigue saliendo el mismo referer en el sitio final (sitio3). Sigo viendo el referer como sitio2.com/?redirect=true , ¿cómo puedo hacerlo para que no se vea el trozo de ?redirect?true?  Mil gracias y perdona las molestias.

Comment: Para que no haya dudas el código que tengo en el sitio2 es así:                        `<?php
  if (isset($_GET["redirect"])) {
    $hash = $_GET["redirect"];
    if ($hash !== "") {

$url = explode("?", $referer); echo $url[0];

        echo "<script>
                window.location.href = 'http://www.sitio3.com';
              </script>";
    }
  }
?>`

Comment: Desde el lado del sitio 2 no se podría, ya que el enlace cuando está ahí realmente es 'sitio2.com/?redirect=true'. El trozo de código que menciono es para agregarlo en sitio 3. En sitio 3 estás obteniendo la URL completa, así que sólo debes agregar ese fragmento ahí. Si aún tienes dudas, tal vez puedas agregar el código del sitio 3 y así podré ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: el problema es que no tengo acceso al sitio3 (al sitio1 y al sitio 2, sí, pero al sitio3 no). Entonces allí no puedo incluir nada en el código del sitio. Debe existir alguna forma de poder hacer la redirección del sitio 2 al sitio 3 sólo cuándo el usuario proviene del sitio 1, pero sin necesidad de que la url contenga ningún token (ya que ahora sí lo incluye con el ?redirect=true y me fastidia con el referer final. Cierto?  Cómo podría hacerlo? perdona tantas molestias..

Comment: Se me ocurre otra posible solución enviando el parámetro por POST en vez de GET. Te sirve de esta manera?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el referer te salga sólo el dominio del sitio, podrías optar por enviar el parámetro por POST. En ese caso para poder realizar la redirección del sitio 1 al sitio 2, deberías utilizar un formulario.

El código sería algo así:

Sitio 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var $form=$(document.createElement('form')).css({display:'none'}).attr("method","POST").attr("action","http://www.sitio2.com/");
    var $input=$(document.createElement('input')).attr('type','hidden').attr('name','redirect').val("true");
    $form.append($input);
    $("body").append($form);
    $form.submit();

</script>
```

Sitio 2:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["redirect"])) {
    $hash = $_POST["redirect"];
    if ($hash !== "") {

        echo "<script>
                window.location.href = 'http://www.sitiofinal3.com';
              </script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto. Eres un crack. Mil gracias!   Por cierto, no tiene nada que ver con esto, pero me gustaría contactar contigo para hacerte una posible propuesta que podría interesarte. Si me das alguna forma de contactar contigo te comento sin compromiso alguno. Gracias!

Comment: @DavidMatas me alegro que te funcionara. Puedes contactarme al correo de mi perfil.

Comment: Hola Jemonge! cómo podría hacer que en el Sitio 2 pudiera poner otra línea adicional en el código para que hubiera otro caso en el que fuera a otra URL el tráfico que provenga de otro Sitio (con otro token). Es decir, ahora mismo el Sitio 1 tiene el código que me pusiste que redirige al Sitio 2 y éste último redirige al Sitio 3. Lo único que quiero hacer es que exista otro "Sitio 1" (pero sin ser el Sitio1 actual), es decir otro caso a más a más, y que vaya al mismo Sitio 2 actual pero con otro Sitio 3 final. Básicamente es porque

Comment: tengo dos entradas de tráfico distintas que quiero llevar a distintos Sitio1 pero mismo Sitio 2 y también con sitios finales (sitio 3) distintos. Mil gracias.